# Google doesn't recognize a 404 status code

Tags: google, google-search-console, googlebot, 404

There are 404 pages with two kinds of `response headers` (copypasted in full length from Chrome DevTools, Network tab):

1. Response headers:

   `cache-control:max-age=0, no-store
   content-type:text/html
   date:Wed, 24 Jan 2018 10:55:59 GMT
   server:Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
   status:404
   x-powered-by:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22`
2. Response headers

   `cache-control:max-age=0, no-store
   cache-control:no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
   content-type:text/html; charset="utf-8"
   date:Wed, 24 Jan 2018 10:55:40 GMT
   expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
   pragma:no-cache
   server:Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
   set-cookie:bypassStaticCache=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly
   set-cookie:bypassStaticCache=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly
   status:404
   x-powered-by:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22`

The pages with the first kind of `response headers` aren't recognized by Google as 404. Instead of 404 alerts the Search Console those pages as duplicate pages without canonical tag.

The pages with the second kind of `response headers` are correctly recognized as 404.

*Not recognized* means: Google calls such pages *Duplicate page without canonical tag*, despite the fact, that developer tools of Firefox and Chrome get correct 404 status code.

*Recognized* means: such pages are called *Not found (404)*, like on the following screenshot:
[image]

**Why is it so?** What prevents the correct status code recognition? Does the answer need additional information? Just say - i'll try to provide it.

**PS**: maybe it is a bug of the new Search Console...? @[JohnMu](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/711/john-mueller)

Comment: I'd recommend getting the headers from `curl --head <url>` or `curl -D - <url>` rather than use chrome.  As DocRoot points out, it looks like you might be trying to set the status in a header field rather than in the first line of the response.   Or it could just be Chrome mucking it up.   You should use curl to see which of those is true.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP response status is indicated by the very first line of the response (the "[Status Line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-22)") - which you aren't currently showing in the output in your question. For a 404 response, you would expect to see something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

> ```
> status:404
> ```

The `Status` response header is non-standard.

Comment: It would make sence for me, if this status would not be recognized in the second case...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? `status:404` is probably ignored in both cases. What is the first line of the response? What does the _browser_ think the response status is? Is Google (GSC I assume?) seeing the second response as a 404 or a "soft-404"?

Comment: as "real" 404 - thats it.
What do you mean with "first line"? - i cited both full responses.

Comment: The output in your question looks like it could be a _parsed response_. In Google Chrome you should have the option to "view source". The very first line of the response should be of the form `HTTP/1.N <CODE> <MESSAGE>`, eg. `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` (as mentioned above) or `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` etc. But even before viewing the headers, "What does the browser think the response status is?" (Network tab of the Developer Tools / Inspector)

Comment: Response headers i cited above are from Chrome developer tools, Network tab. Both kinds of page are shown in Developer tools as 404 pages. In case of page with not-recognized 404 the only content is the text "file not found". In case of recognized 404 the content is a customized (non-standard) HTML-page without any status message, like `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.